# Django: Refactoring models into sub-modules

Tags: python, django, django-models, refactoring

After the models.py in one app grew quite large, I've tried to move some of the classes into subpackages.

The old structure was something like this:

```
# File: assets/models.py
class Asset(...):
    # lots of irrelevant code

# File: widgets/models.py
from assets.models import Asset
class Video(...):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset)
```

This worked without a problem, so I'm not going into further details about the structure.

What I've tried to do now is move the `Asset` class into a submodule. The structure is now as follows:

```
# File: assets/models/__init__.py (of course I deleted the old models.py)
from .assets import Asset

# File: assets/models/assets.py
class Asset(...):
    # lots of irrelevant code

# File: widgets/models.py
from assets.models.assets import Asset
class Video(...):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset)
```

Somehow this doesn't work, and I can't figure out what actually causes the trouble. The error I'm getting is this:

> widgets.video: 'asset' has a relation with model , which has either not been installed or
>   is abstract

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that Django can't reliably detect which app a model belongs to if it's in a nested submodule (ie. not directly inside APPNAME.models).

This is a known problem and can be solved by adding the following lines (in this case to the `Asset` class), thus defining explicitly which app a model belongs to:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'assets'
    ...
```

References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/MmaiKvbDlDc
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14007

Answer (score 0):

You should import from `models` as before:

```
from assets.models import Asset
```

This allows you to always import from `models` but organise the models separately within the `models` directory. It also means, conceptually, that `Asset` is still in `models` as your `ForeignKey` refers to a `assets.models.Asset` object, not `assets.models.assets.Asset`.

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried it, Django still gives the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: @DaveVogt: could you perhaps post the stack trace? Where does Django raise that error?